# How to get time String from current_timestamp().toDate() in cumulocity?

Tags: cumulocity

In my development over cumulocity using CEL, i assume it will return time String like `2017-01-04T20:55:50.365+08:00` by invoking `current_timestamp().toDate()` as below, but it doesn't work. How can i get time String value(like `2017-01-04T20:55:50.365+08:00`) of current time in cumulocity CEL?

```
var timestr = current_timestamp().toDate()
```

Thanks,
ZJP